# Time zone effect on Date to LocalDate conversions for dates far in the future

Tags: date, timezone, jodatime

The following test illustrates something I ran across will investigating `Date` to `LocalDate` conversions.

For my setup, Java 7 & joda-time 2.7, the conversion of `Date` to `LocalDate` and back appears to get a bit off starting around 2038-3-22.

For me, `test_2038_3_21` passes, but `test_2038_3_22` does not.

Is this a known problem, and if so, is there a work around?

```
package com.example;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TimeZoneTest {

    @Test
    public void test_2038_3_21() {
        exerciseDate(2038, 3, 21);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_2038_3_22() {
        exerciseDate(2038, 3, 22);
    }

    static void exerciseDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        TimeZone defaultTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        String defaultUserTimezone = System.getProperty("user.timezone");
        DateTimeZone defaultDateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();

        try {
            for (String timeZoneId : timeZoneIds()) {
                System.setProperty("user.timezone", timeZoneId);
                TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId));
                DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneId));

                LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(year, month, day);
                DateTime dt = ld.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
                Date d = ld.toDate();
                Date dd = dt.toDate();

                LocalDate ld2 = LocalDate.fromDateFields(d);
                DateTime dt2 = ld2.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
                Date d2 = ld2.toDate();
                Date dd2 = dt2.toDate();

                assertEquals(timeZoneId, ld, ld2);
                assertEquals(timeZoneId, dt, dt2);
                assertEquals(timeZoneId, d, d2);
                assertEquals(timeZoneId, dd, dd2);
                assertEquals(timeZoneId, d, dd);
            }
        } finally {
            DateTimeZone.setDefault(defaultDateTimeZone);
            System.setProperty("user.timezone", defaultUserTimezone);
            TimeZone.setDefault(defaultTimeZone);
        }
    }

    static List<String> timeZoneIds() {
        List<String> timeZones = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String timeZoneId : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
            try { // only use time zones that DateTimeZone thinks are valid
                DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneId);
                timeZones.add(timeZoneId);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        return timeZones;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely hitting a DST transition for one of the time zones.

From [the docs for `LocalDate.toDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDate--):

> Converting to a JDK Date is full of complications as the JDK Date constructor doesn't behave as you might expect around DST transitions. This method works by taking a first guess and then adjusting the JDK date until it has the earliest valid instant.

Do note though that future transitions are really just a best guess based on current information.  Time zone rules change regularly.  For something that far out, there could easily be a change between now and then.